# Use ReactivePoll inside an observe (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I'm trying to have a `reactivePoll` inside an `observe` for the reason that I need it to start only after some `req` are fullfil in my app (otherwise it will probably crash), then pass it to a session variable for which I'm using `reactiveValues`. For some reason everytime I perform the change in the variable, it looks like the `reactivePoll` creates a copy of itself and start to perform the checkFunc more than needed. Minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(selectInput("x", "Change options", c(1, 2)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  v <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    print("obs")
    req(input$x)

    v$a <- reactivePoll(5000, session, 
                        checkFunc = function() {
                          print("test")
                          input$x
                        }, valueFunc = function() {
                          print("value")
                          1
                        })

    print(v$a())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, when the selectInput value is changed the print inside the check function evaluates n + 1 times than before.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(selectInput("x", "Change options", c(1, 2)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues()

  a <- reactivePoll(5000, session,
    checkFunc = function() {
      req(input$x)
      print("test")
      input$x
    },
    valueFunc = function() {
      print("value")
      1
    }
  )

  observe({
    print("obs")
    req(input$x)
    v$a <- a()
    print(v$a)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues(
    a = reactivePoll(5000, session,
      checkFunc = function() {
        req(input$x)
        print("test")
        input$x
      },
      valueFunc = function() {
        print("value")
        1
      }
    )
  )  

  observe({
    print("obs")
    req(input$x)
    print(v$a())
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks, it looks like these solutions using a req inside the checkFunc don't work to my real case because it evaluates a change in the checkFunc even if the req aren't met. If you add a first choice empty ("") it will crash.